# D7 RSS Feeds - Omitting Content Fields

Tags: feeds, views

I created a view with an RSS feed on my D7 site. From the XML feed I'd like to remove the author who created the node displayed in my view and the creation date. I've searched everywhere and tried everything, but I can't seem to remove these two fields from my feed.

I only have permissions to work in views so if you have a solution using Views 3 I'd be most appreciative.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify under "Manage Display" how the content you want to feed will look in the "RSS" (or any other) viewmode. By default, you only have the body (or any additional fields) available. To have more control over what's displayed in which viewmode, you can use the [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module. This module allows you (among many other features) to use another layout for this content. By enabling a layout on the viewmode you like, you also get additional fields like for example the Author and the Post date which you then can enable or disable.

Comment: Do I need to have Display Suite installed/enabled in order to change my view with "Manage Display"? I don't see Manage Display in my RSS view so I'm assuming yes. Just want confirmation. Thank you for the quick and helpful reply.

Comment: Ok - just confirmed that I do have Display Suite installed and enabled on the site. How do I 1) configure it to work with an feed w/in a view and 2) use it in the feed view? Sorry, but I haven't worked with D7 before...

Comment: Just go to your content type and click on "Manage Display". Then enable the RSS viewmode on "Custom display settings". Then select a layout (one column for example) and drag the fields around.

Comment: The Content Type edit pages are under the Stucture section of the admin pages -you can't change these display setting from your View editing page (just to be clear).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm giving everything a try now and will let you know how things go.

Comment: I must be dense - I keep changing the fields displayed and layout for my RSS feeds in my Article (nodes) content type, but the changes never save. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're on the right display? Have you set the layout to "one column" for example?

Comment: I finally got it working. Thank you all for your instructions - everyone is now happy with their feeds on the site!